# GWT: Deserialize objects sent/received via websocket

Tags: websocket, gwt, deserialization, gwt-rpc

I would like to analyze messages exchanged between my browser and https://metatraderweb.app. Most communication between client side and server side happens via a GWT signal server using web sockets. Data is sent and received (presumably) as serialized objects.

Binary messages sent and received may look like this (in hex):

```
00000000    10  00  00  00  01  00  00  00  3b  97  ca  77  41  b1  61  98
00000010    ea  f6  81  c4  10  7a  23  c8  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
```

I have no experience in GWT-RPC and the likes but is there a way to serialize the objects that are sent forth and back via the websocket?

Comment: As discussed at https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/q0QxVCumk6I on the gwt mailing list, this is neither gwt nor gwt-rpc (though the compiled JS in the app happens to use the string `gwt` for a variable name and part of a url.